# setting default values for slots ends in loop

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, slot

i'm working on a alexa skill and have some problems with the setting of default values for slots during an dialog model.

I have an intent with 4 slots and i want to give 2 of them at default values at the bedinning. This is my code to try this:

i created an intent object and set the values.

```
    updatedIntent = {
        "name": "Training",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "slot1": {
                "name": "slot1",
                "value": "",  /// HERE I ADDED "" BECAUSE THIS VALUE SHOULD BE FILLED BY THE USER
                "resolutions": {
                    "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                        {
                            "authority": "",
                            "status": {
                                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": {
                                        "name": "Pferde",
                                        "id": "e036baff329d97ae8387f195b27fe9af"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            },
            "slot2": {
                "name": "slot2",
                "value": "test", //HERE FOR SLOT2 I ADDED MY DEFAULT VALUE "TEST"
                "resolutions": {
                    "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                        {
                            "authority": "",
                            "status": {
                                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": {
                                        "name": "Fische",
                                        "id": "4adf750f60e18ab47f596aeb5b838733"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

after that i returned the updatedIntent via :delegate.

```
    this.emit( this.emit(':delegate', updatedIntent));
```

Soo now slo2 is filled an Alexa does not ask me for that. But slot1 is not filled (only with "") so alexa asks me "Give me the value of slot1?" and i give the answer "test". The Input Intent is now filled with slot1=test. But it does not overwrites the "" in the output Intent. So Alexa asks me again "Give me the value of slot1?". And no matter what i say it does not fill the slot1. It ends in a loop.

What do i wrong? Maybe the syntax is wrong? or do i have to asign the input intent opject to updatedIntent?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why setting the value of slot1 to an empty string. If your intention is to set the default value of slot1 to nothing then you don't have to do anything, that's what you get by default. When a slot value is not set the "value" property does not exist in the slot. It only exists if there's a (non empty) value:

```
                       "slots": {
                            "marca": {
                                "name": "marca",
                                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                            },
                            "precio": {
                                "name": "precio",
                                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                            },
                            "color": {
                                "name": "color",
                                "value": "roja",
                                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                            },
                            "talla": {
                                "name": "talla",
                                "value": "grande",
                                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                            }
                        }
```